# Accessing html table from PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I'm really having a hard time with accessing my html table from PHP.

This is what I have:

file.php

```
<?php

  ...some php code
  $someValue = '2012';

?>

<script language='javascript'>
    var table = document.getElementById('tableId');

     for (var i = '<php echo $myVar?>',row; row = table.rows[ '<php echo $myVar?>']; i++) {
        //iterate through rows
        //rows would be accessed using the 'row' variable assigned in the for loop
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
            //iterate through columns
            //columns would be accessed using the 'col' variable assigned in the for loop
            col.innerHTML = '<?php  $someValue; ?>'  
        }  
    }
</script> 

<?php

  ... continue php codes.       
?>
```

Do I make sense here? I wanted to place the `$someValue` to my table cell.

Help

The flow is something like this... I have

file-1.php

- contains my table
- contains file-1.js

file-1.js

- has an ajax object that executes file-2.php

then I wanted file-2.php to access the table in file-1.php
and fill out the cells with the values generated in file-2.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo that variable.

```
<?php echo $someValue; ?>
```

Comment: thanks @Kai Qing, i echo'ed it already but still not showing.. am i accessing the cell correctly?

Comment: If you view source do you get col.innerHTML = '2012'? It could be that php is echoing as expected but your js is never called to actually write the dom element, or is called incorrectly.

Comment: yes, the col.innerHTML has the correct value when i view source.. :( but its not reflecting on my page..

Comment: You should try putting all your js into a window onload listener then: window.onload = function(){ //your code }; it echoes as expected but is likely being called before the dom is actually written. Therefore, tableId is not present and the for loop may have nothing to iterate through.

Answer (score 1):

## You simply forgot to `echo` it out.

```
col.innerHTML = '<?php echo $someValue; ?>';
```

Comment: thanks.. yeah i forgot to echo.. i tried and still its not showing in my table ;(  am i accessing the cell correctly?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using ajax,  send the new values from file2.php in a json form (http://www.json.org/) for eg try this ( http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Introduction-to-JSON-and-PHP)

Then use javascript to get the json values each and then u can update ur html table .

Better use some javascript libraries like Jquery ( http://www.jquery.com/ ) , so that u can do this easily

Comment: thanks @Akhil Thayyil but it is still not showing.. would it matter if my table is inside <div>?

Comment: Am not sure about ur logic , i have corrected it anyways 

var i = '<?php echo $myVar?>';//Changes this
var i = <?php echo $myVar?>;


Check this js in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/A44RV/

Comment: thanks @Akhil hmmm.. because they are different files.. is that possible?

Comment: what i mean is, the file which contains my html table is different from
my php file that tries to access the table..
is that possible?

Comment: what ur saying ? ur doing it in javascript and the output after php parsing contain the javacript+html(including ur tables )+ur processed php code , so all these are finnaly comes under a single page . so how can both be different , pls state ur problem with all possible details then only we can help u at its best

Comment: its something like this: I have file-1.php ->contains my table ->contains file-1.js;;; file-1.js ->has an ajax object that executes file-2.php;; then i wanted file-2.php to access the table in file-1.php and fill out the cells with the values generated in file-2.php is that possible?

Comment: Check edit , and go through the links i have give, i think u need to update a table via ajax , so refer those tutorials.

Comment: thanks a lot @Akhil.. im using the xmlResponse.. hmm the reason I wanted to access it via php is because the file transfer may be big... :( thanks a lot.. il probbly have to return the values then..

Comment: @tinks: if you use jquery the xml also u can parse , just check the jquery ajax documentation, you will get a clear idea there ..

Comment: yes @Akhil i can already parse the xmlresponse but like my file to read could be 4k+ lines :( im thinking if i should just do my file reading in jaavscript :( but i think not a good idea..